# Manhwa where the female lead finds out her magic has been sealed and her husband protects her from her family

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

From what I remember, the female lead had pure white hair and chose to marry her husband to get away from her family. She had a gem on her wrist that all people in that world have, but she couldn’t hide it due to her holy power being sealed away, due to medication she was eating.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When and where did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or locations?

Comment: I don’t remember any names and I read it on a translation site. Another detail tho is everyone in her family had white hair and had the same magic power

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[I Married the Male Lead's Dad](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-married-the-male-leads-dad)***...?

> In my real life, I was happy fawning over Abel Louvremont, the main character of my favorite book ‘Persona.’ But after a fateful car accident, I woke up in ‘Persona,’ but when Abel is still a precious child. Now, as Aisha Heathcliff, I can fangirl adorable Abel up close, squee!! I’ll do anything I can to make sure he is taken care of and gets what he needs! And, somehow, that means I’m engaged to... his dad?!
>
> [image: Promotional art for "I Married the Male Lead's Dad."]

A Korean woman is hit by a truck and reincarnated in the world of a novel she'd read as Aisha Heathcliff, the white-haired daughter of Benjamin, a poor and unknown baron who also has white hair.

Aisha lives in the Cresenta Empire, where everyone is born with one of six magical elements: Fire, Water, Earth, Wind, Light and Darkness. These powers are symbolised by a 'jewel core' located somewhere on the body of each Cresentian. Damage to their jewel cores can be fatal to them, however, so they normally learn to magically conceal them by the age of ten. Aisha was born with the Light element, and her jewel core is located on the inner wrist of her left arm, but for some reason, she can't magically conceal it or use her Light powers.

In the first chapter, Aisha is a guest of Hades Louvremont, a wealthy duke and Fire element user who's summoned her to his mansion in the Northern Lands in order to propose to her. She's unsure about the proposal, since she doesn't know him very well, but agrees to marry him, as she's a simp for his adopted son, Abel -- the protagonist of the novel -- and wants to become his mother.

Hades is very protective of Aisha, and in chapter 24 he asks her about a bottle of pills he sees on her nightstand. She explains that it's medication she's been taking since she was young, which is manufactured at the Holy Temple. She becomes suspicious of these pills when her father comes to visit and asks whether she's still taking them. She subsequently learns that the pills were designed solely for the purpose of suppressing her mana, and that's why she couldn't magically conceal her jewel core or use her Light powers.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/i-married-the-male-leads-dad/info).

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Emily Mercier - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.